# How to write subquery for 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I need to print the student name from the first table and course number from the second table and course title from the third table who choose Physics and chemistry using subquery

```
mysql> select * from tudents;                                                                     

| student_no | student_name | age  |
+------------+--------------+------+
|          1 | Michael      |   19 |
|          2 | Doug         |   18 |
|          3 | Samantha     |   21 |
|          4 | Pete         |   20 |
|          5 | Ralph        |   19 |
|          6 | Arnold       |   22 |
|          7 | Michael      |   19 |
|          8 | Jack         |   19 |
|          9 | Rand         |   17 |
|         10 | Sylvia       |   20 |

mysql> select * from student_enrollment;

+------------+-----------+
| student_no | course_no |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 | CS110     |
|          1 | CS180     |
|          1 | CS210     |
|          2 | CS107     |
|          2 | CS220     |
|          3 | CS110     |
|          3 | CS180     |
|          4 | CS220     |
|          5 | CS110     |
|          5 | CS180     |
|          5 | CS210     |
|          5 | CS220     |
|          6 | CS110     |
|          7 | CS110     |
|          7 | CS210     |

mysql> select * from courses;

+-----------+---------------------+---------+
| course_no | course_title        | credits |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+
| CS110     | Pre Calculus        |       4 |
| CS180     | Physics             |       4 |
| CS107     | Intro to Psychology |       3 |
| CS210     | Art History         |       3 |
| CS220     | US History          |       3 |
```

I'm able to extract the name from the first_table using below query

```
select a.student_name 
from students a 
where a.student_no in (select student_no 
                       from student_enrollment  
                       where course_no in (select course_no 
                                           from courses 
                                           where course_title in ('Physics', 'US History')));
```

I got 210 rows for the below query. What is the error

```
select 
    a.student_name, b.course_no, c.course_title 
from 
    students a, student_enrollment b, courses c 
where 
    a.student_no in (select student_no 
                     from student_enrollment 
                     where b.course_no in (select course_no 
                                           from courses 
                                           where course_title in ('Physics', 'US History')));
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    students.student_name,student_enrollment.course_no,courses.course_title
from students 
join student_enrollment
    on students.student_no=student_enrollment.student_no
join courses
    on courses.course_no=student_enrollment.course_no
where courses.course_title in ('Physics', 'US History');
```